# Как реализовать покупку премиум версии приложения (без рекламы)

Tags: android, admob, in-app-purchases

Здравствуйте. Я делаю премиум апгрейд приложения (ad free), и использую для этого  In app purchase v3 http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html .Тип покупки "не контролируется Google". Основная особенность, я просто не применял покупку (не вызывал метод consume, после удачной покупки), и делал проверку, при запуске приложение, и реклама убиралась. Тестирование проводил указуя id покупки "android.test.purchased". Но спустя некоторое время (день, неделя, месяц) покупка пропадала, и реклама снова появлялась. Поэтому, как можно реализовать Pro-версию приложения, чтобы можно было делать проверку после покупки (при запуске приложения), не используя собственный сервер. SharedPreferences и SQLite не подходит для этого, так после удаления приложения, данные пропадают, и покупка тоже. Какой тип покупки лучше выбрать, чтобы она сохранялась для пользователя навсегда. Нужно делать привязку до Google play аккаунта. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как лучше сделать, или какой тип покупки нужно реализовать в данной ситуации.Большое Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня сделан тип покупки "Контролируется google".
Для проверки покупки можно просто отправить запрос на сервер. При положительном ответе делаю пометку в SharedPreference и убираю рекламу. Если пользователь уже делал покупку, то при вызове play market покупка восстанавливается.

Если у вас тип "Не контролируется google" и вы хотите сохранить состояние покупки на долго, то нужен свой сервер, на котором в базе будет храниться пользователь и состояние, иначе лучше выбрать "Контролируется google".

Один вид покупок для разовых штук(например деньги или перки в игре), а другой для постоянных(например удаление рекламы или покупка премиум версии).

Comment: Спасибо, немножко разъяснилась ситуация.

Comment: А можно ли протестировать ее используя тестовый id покупки? Или только через альфа-версию приложения и группу Google?

Comment: @АлександрШевчук Протестировать можно. Нужен акк не разработчика + подписанное приложение.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь.